# Determine if "this" was specified

Tags: javascript

I want to safely parse the value of `this`, in a global function, while accounting for whether `this` was explicitly set via `call`, `apply` or `bind` on the function.

In NodeJS, the following seems to work correctly:

```js
function checkThis() {
    const defaultThis = require.main.children[0].exports;

    console.log(this === defaultThis);
}

checkThis(); //=> true

checkThis.call(); //=> false

checkThis.apply(); //=> false
```

Is there any JavaScript-generic alternative to this that would work both in browsers and NodeJS?

Comment: MDN doc : `If the method is a function in non-strict mode, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object` thus in the browser it would be `window`

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) in browser land.

> The global globalThis property contains the global this value, which is akin to the global object.

Note the comment by @Simon, your code in your example will not work in non-strict mode

Answer (score 1):

When working with `this`, make sure to always use strict mode to get the value that was actually passed, not something coerced to an object or defaulted to the global object.

However, it is not really possible to detect whether a `this` argument was explicitly set with `call`/`apply`/`bind` or whether the function was called directly, *every* call does pass a `this` argument even if it's `undefined`:

```js
function checkThis() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this);
}

checkThis();        // undefined
checkThis.call();   // undefined
checkThis.apply();  // undefined
checkThis.bind()(); // undefined
```

If you really needed to detect `call`/`apply`/`bind`, you'd need to overwrite these methods on your concrete function.